# Enable cell edit only when adding a row in grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

```
$("#btn_Add").click(function(e) {
             $('#costCdGrid').jqGrid('addRowData', 0, {},'first',true);// 
             $("#costCdGrid").jqGrid('setRowData',0,false, {'background-color' : '#D6E8FF'}); 
       });
```

I just want to enable cell editing whenever i add the row using button (btn_Add) otherwise the fields in the grid remains not editable

Comment: Can you please post more information on jqGrid settings? It is important to know when the cell editing is finished. Whet you mean with cell editing - when the entire row is in edit mode or only per cell edit is enabled - i.e the grid option **cellEdit** is set to true?

Comment: yes, i need entire row to be in edit mode only when btn_Add is clicked otherwise disable the cell edit